Did Michael Servetus and Oneness Pentecostals have the same beliefs about the Trinity?
Did Michael Servetus and Oneness Pentecostals have the same beliefs about the Trinity?
Edit: I did some additional research and this came up on Copilot:

In summary, while there are similarities in their rejection of the Trinity, Oneness Pentecostals have a distinct set of beliefs that go beyond Servetus’s unitarian perspective. They emphasize the singular nature of God and the personal manifestations of that oneness.


It would be beneficial if you could give some specifics as to what you are looking for. I would hate for your question to be closed due to a lack of clarity.

The Stack Exchange platform is an academic archive of material and contributions are expected to have some measure of research provided for the readership. At present, I would suggest that this question may risk closure due to 'lack of clarity and detail'. You are expecting your readership to look up data which ought to have been provided by the question itself. An edit, providing links to content and with informative support, may well save the contribution from closure. Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Do you mean was Servetus a modalist, or did Servetus think Trinitarians were actually modalists?

Assuming that the audience knows everything, or that they should look it up themselves, is not a good way to ask a question on this site. For this to be a useful question, it should be self--contained, providing explicit definitions of "what Micahael Servetus believed" and "what Oneness Pentecostals believe", preferably by quoting publications by those two sources.

As the question is worded now, it could receive an answer such as "No. The Trinity is such a large and complex subject that it would be almost impossible for two people to independently agree on all possible aspects of it.".

I believe Servetus was much more aligned with modern day Biblical Unitarians than Oneness Pentecostals.

Next time I'll add more information. I did some additional research and this came up on Copilot.                                                                                                                                               "In summary, while there are similarities in their rejection of the Trinity, Oneness Pentecostals have a distinct set of beliefs that go beyond Servetus’s unitarian perspective. They emphasize the singular nature of God and the personal manifestations of that oneness.

I've just included your above comment in the body of your question in the hope it will result in some interest and answers.

P.S. Your latest question on the differences between Christianity Stack Exchange and Biblical Hermeneutics was sent here: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7556/what-are-the-differences-between-christianity-stack-exchange-and-biblical-her
